# Popup box should not be display when click on facebook like button

Tags: facebook, button, popup, facebook-like

**Question:** When I click on facebook like button a pop up box is appear. But I don't want to display it. When we click on facebook like button just my page should be like, box should not be display.
Can I hide this box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use iframe to show like button, comment popup will not be display when user click on like button.

See link below for more details:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

See iframe sample code to display like button:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;width&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=35&amp;appId=248175312034010" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this possible for this pop up to appear only to those who didn't liked it already, I mean it should check the cookie and see if the visitor has signed in to his fb account and if he already had liked the page then this pop up doesn't show.